# What is the regex for matching any numbers, with spaces between them?

Tags: regex

I searched and tried all possible regex solutions, but I couldn't find any answer. I'm looking for a regex, which matches the numbers with any spaces between them.

For example, the following senctences:

> 12 Voorbeeld3 4Voorbeeld5 6 test 777
>
> Example1 2 33 4test

So the regex would match only `12`, `6` and `777` in the first sentence
and only `2` and `33` in the second sentence. So every digit(s) numbers which are between the spaces.

I tried the regex to looking for the whitespaces. For example, the `(?<!\s[\d+])` But it match's only the single digits, and not multiple digits.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about at the beginning and end of a string?

Comment: `[]` is reserved to character class, so `[\d+]` matches a single digit or a `+` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **whitespace boundaries** here:

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)
```

*Details*

- `(?<!\S)` - left-hand whitespace boundary
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?!\S)` - right-hand whitespace boundary

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hq1GRU/1).

Why not `(?<=\s)\d+(?=\s)`? Because this pattern *requires* at least one whitespace on each side of the digit sequence. The whitespace boundaries in this solution also allow matching at the start and end of the string.

Why not `\b` word boundaries? Because the question is about matching numbers that have whitespace as boundaries, and `\b\d+\b` also matches `1` in a#1#b`.

Comment: Surprised to get an answer ron this later, which is really appreciated! Thank you, Wiktor!

Answer (score 7):

The RegExp you're looking for is the following:

```
\b(\d+)\b
```

The above RegExp will match any number between two [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), and, therefore, it will match:

- `"123 "`
- `" 123"`
- `" 123 "`

**Use the `g` modifier** to match all the occurrences (all the numbers). You can find a working example [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/uF3vG2/2).

JavaScript example:

```js
var text = "12 Voorbeeld3 4Voorbeeld5 6 test 777",
    exp = /\b(\d+)\b/g,
    match;

while (match = exp.exec(text)) {
    console.log(match[0]);
}
```

Result:

```
12
6
777
```

Comment: Thanks for your well written answer!

Answer (score 2):

Groups of digits surrounded by whitespace (or at the beginning/end of string) can be matched using word boundaries:

```
\b\d+\b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds:

```
(?<=\s)\d+(?=\s)
```

Or if lookarounds are not available then use captured groups:

```
\s(\d+)\s
```

And use captured group #1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like so: `\b(\d+)\b`. This will check to see if you have one or more digits surrounded by spaces. A sample of the regular expression can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/xV6rI0/1).